# Post Notification doesn't work on Poptorootviewcontroller in iOS

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I'm implementing More options menu(like android three dots More option) using Post notification in my ViewController.

In all other view controllers, i'm having HomeButton and More option button in the top of the all pages.

By using post notification, i can display the more option view to other view controllers. The more option button works in other view controllers, after i navigate to that page.

But After go to homepage using HomeButton from other view controllers and then tapping the More options button won't work. After that, the more option in other view controllers also won't work.

I've added the following code to Homebutton Action.

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

I hope the error could be in Homebutton action.

FYI: I've created a view for more option. Also added a table view to that view. when user clicks that more option button, i'm just showing the view. when user clicks one of the menu in more option, then i'll hide that view. i've hide the view in viewDidload.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I guess when you popToRootView Your controller who are observer are poped from navigation stack so they can not receive your post notification..
Try to log self.navigationcontroller.viewcontroller and check are they still in the navigation stack or not..

Comment: Yeah. the view controller gets cleared after pop. But i've implemented Postnotification's methods in that root view controller's .m file. So it supposed to work. I've checked out the work flow in that view controllers using breakpoints. It goes into that code . But only view is not showing.

Comment: okey, then where did you fire this notifications?

Comment: I'm using the following code in all view controller's MoreOptionButton Action.                                                                                 
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"MoreOptions" object:nil userInfo:userDict];`
    
So, when i make a click on the more button the notification will be fired.